# To fetch and verify the NSData(of image) at the server side in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, objective-c

I am sending a post request to the server on the click of submit button and sending the image data and aspx form itself. Here is my code......

```
 NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlName];   //..... this is my url name.....
 NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:postURL];
 [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
 NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
 [postRequest addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
 [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"myemailcheck_kiransalke@yahoo.com.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:imgdata];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&err];
```

My question is, how can i fetch and decode the image data at the server side. I am using the "C# .Net". So pls, give me the solution in .net langauge.

Kindly, help me out of this.